# Pygments style not being applied in Jekyll blog

Tags: python, html, css, markdown, pygments

http://joshhornby.co.uk/2012/11/14/test-test-test.html

As you can see from the link the code at the bottom is just yellow. No styling is being applied. I have installed pygments through the terminal and the stylesheets are all there and working. I am using jekyll so markdown files are created then turned into .html pages.

I also have it as pygments: true in the .yml file

EDIT:
Strange i had to change my markdown in the .yml file to markdown: maruku. And it seems to be working more than in was before but what ever style i add there is always a yellow highlight over the code, and the code is never styled as i thought!

Answer (score 1):

Strange i had to change my markdown in the .yml file to markdown: maruku. All working now.